# /sys/firmware/efi/efivars mount point does not exist on artix (QEMU on arch) EFI variables are not supported on this system

Tags: boot, virtual-machine, grub, qemu, efi

I'm trying to install Artix Linux on a virtual machine before I install it on actual hardware. I'm using QEMU.

When trying to install GRUB via

```sh
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootfloader-id=grub
```

I get the error

```
EFI variables are not supported on this system.
EFI variables are not supported on this system.
grub-install: error: efibootmgr failed to register the boot entry: No such file or directory
```

After following a few guides I was directed to run the command `modprobe efivarfs` outside of chroot then run:

```sh
mount -t efivarfs efivarfs /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
```

Which returns the error:

```
mount: /sys/firmware/efi/efivars: mount point does not exist.

       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call
```

I downloaded OpenRC ISO from here: https://artixlinux.org/download.php

and I was following this guide specifically on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9Uv9fNSIzw

My base system is Arch Linux (which is slightly different to the video as they were running windows but I don't think that should cause problems).

Comment: The guide you posted specifically says for Virtualbox with UEFI.

Comment: does QEMU not use UEFI? Or am I meant to enable it?

Comment: No, it doesn't by default and the same goes for Virtualbox. Here's a guide for Ubuntu: https://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2021/04/how-to-boot-uefi-on-qemu.html I suggest you do your own research.

Comment: I might be wrong but it's possible to install artix without uefi right?

Comment: Sure, it's the Legacy/CSM/"BIOS" mode but then you won't be installing Grub for UEFI, commands are vastly different. Again, do your research as this is very basic, trivial.

Comment: I have successfully done my research :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable UEFI on QEMU, if you are using virtmanager (like me) it's very easy to do.

Navigate through Edit>Preferences then click on New VM and set x86 firmware to UEFI and if you did so successfully you should see a different boot up screen

[Preferences menu image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLU9I.png)

OR alternatively if you dont want to use UEFI follow this guide: https://wiki.artixlinux.org/Main/Installation

And use

`grub-install --recheck /dev/sda`
instead of

`grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=grub`